# creating python keyed arrays

Tags: python

im calling them keyed arrays because if i knew what they were called i could find the answer myself  =-)

ok, for example:

```
parser = OptionParser(conflict_handler="resolve")
parser.add_option("-x", dest="var_x",  help="")
parser.add_option("-y", dest="var_y",  help="")


(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

generates an option object that can be used like this:

```
foobar = options.var_x
```

what are these called and where would i find some documentation on how to create and use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One poss is to wrap a dictionary in an object see below for class definition:

```
class Struct:
def __init__(self, **entries): 
    self.__dict__.update(entries)
```

Then just use a dictionary in constructor like so:

```
adictionary = {'dest':'ination', 'bla':2}
options = Struct(**adictionary)
options.dest
options.bla
```

options.dest  will return 'ination'

options.bla  would return 2

Answer (score 2):

One class that does something very similar is [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple

In [2]: Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

In [4]: p = Point(1, 2)

In [5]: p.x
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: p.y
Out[6]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `help(options)` at the interactive terminal, you'll see this is an `optparse.Values` instance. It's not intended for making your own things, really.

Using attribute access for key–value pairs is usually silly. Much of the time people who insist on it should really just be using a dict.

The main built-in way to do something along these lines is `collections.namedtuple`.